# Esconder controles para o flash (swf)?

Tags: html, flash

Como é a maneira correta de ocultar os controles no SWF? Pra quando o usuário clicar com o botão direito do mouse não aparecer as opções...

Esses são os controles:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa img aqui é o que quero que fique aproximadamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se é com o `<embed>` ou o `<object>` ou se é com action script mesmo... :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso por por AS assim:

```
var meuMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
meuMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
stage.contextMenu = meuMenu;
```

<s>Além de ocultar as os controles você pode tentar usar o proprio ActionScript e ocultar o contextmenu, assim:</s>

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {});
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CONTEXT_MENU, function(e:MouseEvent):void {});
```

Comment: Hummmm, vou usar esse!

Comment: @JacksonAntunes tem uma de desabilitar o contextMenu, mas eu sublinhei pois não testei, mas assim que testar eu confirmo se funciona

Answer (score 2):

É no `object`.

Dentro dele coloque:

```
<param name="menu" value="false" />
```

E dentro da tag `embed` coloque:

```
menu="false"
```